# How to calculate t-statistics in generalised least squares?

Tags: statistics, least-squares, linear-regression

As the question states, how would you calculate the t-statistics in GLS? Is it just the same as in OLS? And are these results still reliable?

I have heteroskedastic data and so am using GLS, but I'm not sure if the calculations for t-statistics change or the values are less reliable?

Comment: Please provide additional context.  This question may be better suited on the [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Not really sure how to add much more context @JHF, the question is relatively general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The t-statistics are computed in the usual manner: take $\hat\beta_i$ and divide it by the square root of the ith diagonal of the estimated GLS covariance matrix.

By the way, in a linear regression setting you do not have to perform GLS. Modern approaches favor OLS with standard errors adjusted to reflect the heteroskedasticity, as available in any reliable statistical package.

OLS will go through the means of the data, which seems most sensible. GLS  will not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is the reason that GLS is not applied in general because estimating the covariance matrix is very difficult (or maybe even impossible)? Also, how is this standard error adjustment done?

Comment: I can only refer you to basic econometrics test, perhaps the two best being Stock & Watson and the other is Wooldridge.  I once taught out of Stock and Watson to undergrad. It''s good, but was the required text by my department.  On my own I would have used something more challenging like Wooldridge.